# Unit tests (PHPUnit): create separate project just for testing?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm writing some unit tests (PHPUnit) for a project that will be used by another project. The project that I am testing has a class that will include files that will be present only in the other project.

Now how do I write a unit test for this class without having the files that it needs to include available? Would you recommend setting up a complete testing project with stub files (the file in question is a file that contains some settings) and running all the unit tests there? Or should I create directories and files using for example the `setUp()` method?

*Edit:*

**To be more specific**, I have a base project A, which is a website. I have a project B, which contains a class that generates a form. The form class will be installed in project A using Composer. The form class will in project A check for the existence of a dir with a settings file. If it exists, it will include it and load the settings in it. To test the form class, do you think I should create a project C (just for testing) which installs project B and in which I set up the directory with the settings file for testing? Or do you think it's a better way to go to create the directory with the settings file in project B itself? The latter seems a bit odd to me, as I don't want to have all this unit testing material available in project A when I composer-install project B in it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!! To everything:

**Now how do I write a unit test for this class without having the files that it needs to include available?**

You can create test fixtures.  What is the specification your programming your code to? As you develop your code are you using a test file? reading documentation? Given a specification by the client? You could create an input file that fulfills the spec and provide it to your function.

**Would you recommend setting up a complete testing project with stub files (the file in question is a file that contains some settings) and running all the unit tests there?**

Yes, but only the absolute smallest amount of tests necessary to programmatically ensure that the functionality that you are saying you're providing your client is being delivered!  If the function is provided a file path and parses it and then loads the settings I feel like there needs to be at least a couple test cases that ensure that a file can be read from the operating system.  Having a fixture file that your test loads to verify that the file opening logic is correct should be a pretty reliable test. I think the tricky part is minimizing the number of these tests.

For example, if you need to test your settings parsing logic, it may seem easy to create a settings file and have your test load and parse that settings file.  For a couple tests this will be plenty fast and reliable. But as your test suite grows it becomes orders of magnituded slower than in memory tests.  Instead of going through the file system to test the settings parsing logic, you could excercise a settings parsing function directly by providing it with the string contents of the file.  This way you could build a settings string in memory, in your test function and pass it into the parsing function, avoiding any file system reads.  If the file is too large and expects a file like object so that it can incrementally read data from the file system you could create an in memory stub object which you could use.

I'm not sure of the php api for that but if there is like a readline method you could create a fake file object provide it with the PHP file api and create your fake settings file in memory during the test, also avoiding the file system.

**Or should I create directories and files using for example the setUp() method?**

What is the benefit of this over having a static file? In my experiences minimizing test complexity and test logic is huge for test suite maintenance and performance.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive explanation! I could have been more specific in what I am testing. I have updated my question with some more information. If you have any additions to your answer, I would be delighted to hear them.

Answer (score 0):

You could create/delete the files and directories during setup and tear down, but be aware that this can make your tests flakey as sometimes files can not be deleted, e.g. due to lock issues or when a test fails and tear down is not called.

A safer way to interact with "your local filesystem" is [vfsStream](https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream) which will never actually write to disk. The documentation contains a nice basic example both for using the filesystem directly or using vfsStream to mock the filesystem access: https://github.com/mikey179/vfsStream/wiki/Example

Comment: I have edited my question to be a bit more specific, as I'm really wondering about this question but you guys are the only two that answered. If you have any time, would you mind giving a last comment on the issue?

Comment: @minitauros I was just composing another answer, but after I while I realised it will still be vague. If you just want a general reply: Do unit tests in project B and acceptance tests for how project A will use it, i.e. how the form with settings behaves, in project A. For a more detailed answer we would actually need to see the code and I fear it will not fit in the scope of an answer here

Comment: About that last piece: I agree, I don't think it will fit in the scope of the answer here :). So you'd say just include the unit tests in project B, and don't care about all the tests being included when it is installed into project A?

Comment: Exactly. Project B only cares it works by itself. If integration in project A surfaces a bug in project B, you add a new unit test & fix it in project B. You can't anticipate all ways B will be integrated and all use cases, so it's pointless to test for them.To be fair, I'm coming from Open Source, so I'm biased towards communicating between projects instead of pulling everything into one source.